# Does Windows 7 have limitations on search/copy functions?

Tags: windows-7

When you're trying to search and copy multiple files within Windows 7, is there any type of limitations that I should be worried about? When I say that, I mean things like memory, processor, etc...

Here is/was my scenario... I have a 500GB external hard drive with a bunch of music on it. I did a search on the HD for "Type:MP3" so I could find all music on it since it is scattered between a lot of different folders. My search result returned over 8,900 different files and was roughly 6-8GB (can't remember off the top of my head, it may have been a little more). So I did Ctrl+A to select all the files and attempted to copy them to my desktop folder I had created. After a while of watching nothing happen, I attemtped to load something else on the PC, like the control panel, but it was blank, nothing displayed.
The "copying files" window never displayed either to show me anything was happening.

Comment: How long did you wait after ctrl+a? it may take some time to select that many files on an external usb drive, be patient, loading something else just made the situation worse.

Comment: I have copied thousands and hundreds of GB in a single operation.  Any limits would be in the tens of thousands if not millions and the hundreds if not thousands of GB.

Comment: Have you thought about maybe performing `chkdsk` on your external hard drive to eliminate hard disk/file system problems?

Comment: Well, both drives the be on the safe side.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, but if you wanna try using commandline, here's how you could do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472692/how-to-copy-a-directory-structure-but-only-include-certain-files-using-windows

Answer (score 0):

There are no limitations, but you've to keep some details in mind:

> I did a search on the HD for "Type:MP3" so I could find all music on it since it is scattered between a lot of different folders. My search result returned over 8,900 different files and was roughly 6-8GB (can't remember off the top of my head, it may have been a little more)

Windows uses Indexing Service to speed up searching. The Index only runs slowly in the background to update itself when the computer is idle or at low usage. It may not have had time to finish updating the index list. Be sure to use [Advanced Search](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/36599-search-windows-7-a.html) and enable `Searching non-indexed locations` to get **all** your files in search results

> So I did Ctrl+A to select all the files and attempted to copy them to my desktop folder I had created. After a while of watching nothing happen, I attemtped to load something else on the PC, like the control panel, but it was blank, nothing displayed. The "copying files" window never displayed either to show me anything was happening.

Thats because Windows is "*preparing to copy files*". [One of the things it does is to get the filesizes for the entire copy operation to make a better guesstimate about the time the copy will take](https://superuser.com/a/783817/418201).

What makes it worse, is that you're using external drive (in USB enclosure?) and they are typically 5400 rpm and therefore slow. Combined with USB speed limit, typical read speed for them is about 30-40 MB/s, while internal 7200 rpm drives are easily achieve 70-100 MB/s long-term average rate.

So, all things considered, you just had to wait more, that's the way it works. Alternatively you could use third-party file manager, or software like [TeraCopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeraCopy) to speed up things.

> TeraCopy uses dynamically adjusted buffers to reduce seek times.
>   Asynchronous copy speeds up file transfer between two physical hard
>   drives. The processes can be paused or resumed.
>
> In case of transfer errors, TeraCopy will try several times; after
>   that, it skips the faulty file and proceeds with the rest of the
>   operation. TeraCopy also shows failed file transfers and allows the
>   user to fix the problem and recopy the problematic files.
>
> TeraCopy can replace Explorer copy and move functions. The author
>   asserts that it has full Unicode support.
>
> This software integrates into the Windows Operating System and
>   (optionally) appears whenever you cut/copy files using Windows
>   Explorer. TeraCopy asks for the destination folder along with a list
>   of the last 5 destinations used by you to paste the files. You may
>   choose the destination directly from the list without the hassle of
>   moving to it in Windows Explorer.